# population after $ 4 \ $ years

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the population model $ \frac{dp}{dt}=p(2-P)(p-5) , \ \ p(0)=300 \ $ , where $ t $ in years . Find the population after $ 10 $ years .

**Answer:**

We have to solve it graphically because analytical approach becomes complicated as I tried .

To solve graphically , we need to find the equilibrium points as follows :

$ \frac{dp}{dt}=0 \ implies \ p=0,2,5 \ $ .

In the range  $  0 <p \ $ , $ \frac{dp}{dt}>0 \ $ ,

In $ (0,2) \ $ we get   $ \frac{dp}{dt} <0 \ $ ,

In $ (2,5) \ $ , we get $ \frac{dp}{dt} >0 \ $ ,

When  $ p>5 \ $ , we get  $ \frac{dp}{dt} \ $

Thus the direction field as follows :

[image]

**But I am Unable to draw the solution curve in order to predict the population after $ 4 \ $ years .**

**I need help .**

Comment: This is a separable ODE that you can solve explicitly by using partial fractions.

Comment: impossible to find analytically because constant multiples in partial fractions goes to the  power of logerithmic function .

Comment: Graphically, follow an arrow down from the initial condition. It will converge to p=5 after some time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate it and solve it exactly by writing $$\left(\frac 1{p(2-p)(p-5)}\right)dp=dt$$ and breaking up the left side as partial fractions.  You will get $t$ as a function of $p$.  You can then invert that numerically if you want. 
 If a graphical solution is acceptable, note that $\frac {dp}{dt}(0)\approx -300^3$ so the population will decrease *very* rapidly.  As you have found when $p=5$ you have $\frac {dp}{dt}=0$ so the population will never decrease below $5$.  After $4$ or $10$ years the population will be very close to $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Decomposing by partial fractions,

I get

$-\frac{1}{10}\ln p +\frac{1}{6}\ln (p-2) -\frac{1}{15}\ln (p-5) = t + c$

Further simplifying, you get

$ln\left(\dfrac{(p-2)^5}{p^3(p-5)^2}\right) = 30t + C$

Could you put the intial value and get C

By substituting the value of $t = 0$ and $p = 300$ you get $C = 1.000198 $ $\approx 1.0$

$\dfrac{(p-2)^5}{p^3(p-5)^2} = e^{301}$ when t = 10

$e^{301}$ is a very large number.

Notice the expressions in the numerator and the denominator are of the same degree. For normal values of  p >5 (even large) it becomes 1. For this to be as large as $e^{301}$, it should be asymptotic in nature. So it should be either p close to zero or five.  It cannot be close to 0 because the numerator will become negative.  Thus p should be very close to 5 and **not** 5. Thus it is $5.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001$ or something like that.

Goodluck.

Comment: how do You find $ P $ explicitly in terms of $ t \ $ ?  You must follow graphical approach .

Comment: Please see the explanation analytically.  I must agree that this is a crazy problem.